# PHP MySQL query using UNIONs and locating which table the data came from

Tags: php, mysql, union

So I have a query that I am selecting values from two different tables and UNIONizing them together. I need to know where which entry came from as I need to form a different URL for each. What is the best way and proper syntax to tag both of these SELECT queries. Any help would be appreciated. Code to follow:

```
    $query = "SELECT newsletter_id id, newstitle title FROM tbl_news WHERE (newstitle LIKE '%".stripslashes($rowCont->fname)."%' && newstitle LIKE '%".stripslashes($rowCont->lname)."%') || (newsletter_content LIKE '%".stripslashes($rowCont->fname)."%' && newsletter_content LIKE '%".stripslashes($rowCont->lname)."%') SET @type = news
    UNION
    SELECT event_id id, event_title title FROM tbl_event WHERE ((event_title LIKE '%".stripslashes($rowCont->fname)."%' && event_title LIKE '%".stripslashes($rowCont->lname)."%') || (event_content LIKE '%".stripslashes($rowCont->fname)."%' && event_content LIKE '%".stripslashes($rowCont->lname)."%')) SET @type = event";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $i = 0;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        if($table_name == table1) { //SIMULATED TABLE NAME VARIABLE IF STATEMENT, NEED TO KNOW HOW TO GET TABLE NAME FOR SORTING
            echo "<p><a style='color:#00aeef' href='http://www.url1.com/display.php?article_=".$row["id"]."'>".$row["title"]."</a></p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p><a style='color:#00aeef' href='http://www.url1.com/display.php?article_=".$row["id"]."'>".$row["title"]."</a></p>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a comment to let you know that **all mysql_* functions are deprecated...** You can use mysqli or pdo. :)

Comment: @SilentByte I see your reasoning, but it would be more trouble than it's worth. It's a single instance use in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to include a literal in the select list of each query, for example:

```
SELECT 'q1' AS source, newsletter_id id, ...
UNION
SELECT 'q2' AS source, event_id id, ...
```

---

As an aside, consider using `UNION ALL` operator in place of the `UNION` operator, if removing duplicates is not a requirement.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. It was difficult searching for this online which is reason for the Stack Overflow post. Point for collective communities!